# 'CMake test failed with errors' in CLion

Tags: linux, windows, make, ide, cmake

Every time I try to build a project in CLion, regardless the toolchain, this error appears:

[image]

```
    -- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2019.2.2/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe"

    is not able to compile a simple test program.

   It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/VÃ­ctor/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build17193828646428762434/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make.exe cmTC_60a1a/fast 
    C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_60a1a.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_60a1a.dir/build
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/VÃ�ctor/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build17193828646428762434/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_60a1a.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
    C:\PROGRA~2\MINGW-~1\I686-8~1.0-P\mingw32\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_60a1a.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c C:\Users\Vâ”œÂ¡ctor\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment\_build17193828646428762434\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
    gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Vâ”œÂ¡ctor\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment\_build17193828646428762434\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmTC_60a1a.dir\build.make:65: CMakeFiles/cmTC_60a1a.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/VÃ�ctor/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build17193828646428762434/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:120: cmTC_60a1a/fast] Error 2




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/VÃ­ctor/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build17193828646428762434/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/VÃ­ctor/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build17193828646428762434/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Error code: 1
```

I think it might be because of non-ASCII characters in the path (í), but I am not sure. The path `"C:/Users/VÃ­ctor/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build17193828646428762434/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log"` does not exist in my computer, so it's impossible to retrieve the error log.

Comment: Offhand, if this is the case, perhaps it might be worthwhile to look at the CMake options (below the `Toolchain` settings, I assume), and see if setting  the temporary directory for CMake is an option.

Comment: I didn't find a way to do that.

Comment: Hmm. Well, you could always reinstall and try a different, global path (if you haven't already). This is typically done by selecting the installation directory manually and changing it and/or installing a program for "all users" (not just the current user, which often uses "AppData").

Comment: Otherwise, [CMake](https://cmake.org/) is available as a stand-alone program for Windows and can build whatever you need, assuming you have some pre-made CMake files or similar.